# Question about UK short-term student visa online application form

Tags: student-visa, uk-visa

I'm currently a master candidate enrolled in a university in China, I'm going to visit Newcastle University for a five-month research exchange. When I fill in the online form to apply a short-term student visa of UK, there's some items makes me confused.

*1.Have you been unconditionally accepted or are you enrolled on a course of study in the UK*

> I'm going to do research as a student, no course of study will be
>   taken. Right now I have an invitation letter from the research group
>   at Newcastle University. Should I answer **"No"** here? Or I should answer "**Yes**" with some kind of offer showing that I'm unconditionally accepted ?

*2. What is the name of the course?*

> Is it OK to answer "research training"?

*3.What level of qualification is expected?*

> Is it OK to answer "master research training"?

Any help will be appreciated.